# Compact set notation

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $m\geq 0$ denote some mass in a container. $V(m)$ is strictly decreasing.

We now remove some mass $x$ from the container. We remove as little mass as possible, but we want $V(m) \geq \bar V$. We cannot remove more than $m$. In other words, $x$ is given by

$$ x(m) = \arg\min_{z \in [0, m]} | V(m-z) - \bar V| \tag1$$

This deals with the corner cases: Whenever $V(m)$ already above $\bar V$, we can only reduce absolute value by removing negative $z$, which is forbidden. Whenever $V(0) < \bar V$, $x(m) = m$.

---

Now, I would rather have a set definition. My approach:

$$ x(m) = \min \{ z \in [0, m] : V(m-z) \geq \bar V\} \tag 2$$

however when $V(0) < \bar V$, the set is empty. How can I incorporate that whenever $V(0) < \bar V$, $x(m) = m$?

Comment: There appears to be a mistake in your last sentence. More precisely: What is $z$ supposes to be here?

Comment: Also, you seem to be confused about the terminology $\min_{z \in [0,m]} \ldots$. It seems you want $x(m) = \{ z \in [0,m] \mid | V(m-z) - \bar{V} | \text{ is minimal} \}$. This is not what you've written.

Comment: I'm still confused. Should $x(m)$ be a value for $z$ or for $|V(m-z) - \bar{V}|$?

Comment: @StefanMesken OOOOH I just realized (1) had min instead of argmin... I'm so sorry! I hope that cleared it up.

Comment: Exactly. But (1) is: "Construct $|V(m-z) - \bar{V} |$ for all $z \in [0,m]$" Now take the minimal value of $|V(m-z) - \bar{V}|$ that you've constructed.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then I correctly guessed what you meant and my answer does apply.

Comment: If $V$ is continuous then surely you get either $x(m) = 0$ or $V(m-x(m)) = \bar V$ or $x(m)=m$. I feel like these problems might be resolved by going back a few steps and seeing if there’s a simpler way forward based on what things you already know.

Comment: @DanRobertson The usage of $\min$ suggests, at least to me, that the function $z \mapsto V(z)$ is continuous at least in a small neigborhood of $V^{-1}\{\bar{V}\}$? Or to phrase is differently: Why do we even know that this mininum exists?

Comment: @StefanMesken I suppose you’re getting at the fact that continuous functions on compact domains attain their bounds. However monotone functions on compact domains also attain their boundaries and as $f(z)=|V(m-z) - \bar V|$ (with the domain $[0,m]$) may be split into the union of (one or) two monotone functions on compact domains, it attains its bounds whether or not it is continuous.

Comment: @DanRobertson Right, I've actually forgotten about that... Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

You could write
$$
x(m) = \begin{cases}
m & \text{, if } V(0) < \bar{V}, \\
\min \{ z \in [0,m] \mid V(m-z) \ge \bar{V} \} & 
\text{, otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
Alternatively
$$
x(m) = \begin{cases}
\max \{ z \in [0,m] \mid \ V(z) \ge \bar{V} \} & \text{, if } V(0) \ge \bar{V}, \\
m &
\text{, otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$